page.click() no funciona - Puppeteer en Docker
Estoy trabajando en la automatización de un sitio web.
Mi script básicamente ingresa a un sitio web donde debes iniciar sesión para continuar con el proceso.
El problema es que al parecer la función "clic" no funciona cuando se ejecuta en docker (funciona local y headless), aunque encuentra los selectores, al "clic" termina saliendo por tiempo de espera.
He leído que a veces esto causa problemas.
¿¿Algunas ideas??
Ya he probado a esperar el selector, pinchando directamente, incluso centrándome en él.
Comparto algo del código y las versiones de Docker y Puppetiteer que estoy usando.
const selector = "#loginRegisterTabs > ul > li:nth-child(1)";
await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 30000 });
await page.focus(selector); // Opt
await page.click(selector);

FROM ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:22.14.0
> "puppeteer": "^22.14.0"

¡Gracias!
Saludos

Claro!
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    })
   await page.goto("https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/");
   const selector = "#loginRegisterTabs > ul > li:nth-child(1)";
   await page.waitForSelector(selector);
   await page.click(selector);

Por ejemplo este codigo debería acceder a la pestaña de logueo de la primer pantalla.
Las cookies pueden ignorarse, puesto que están tratadas.
Ya probé con varios tiempos de espera y ya probé que el elemento se encuentra (verificandolo via codigo e imprimendo los selectores presentes)

Gracias Marcos!

Gracias Julim! Por lo general, lo que primero tenes que hacer es esperar a que la página se cargue completamente. ¿Podes agregar la parte del código donde haces el page.goto? Además de eso otra forma de buscar un elemento es utilizar page.$(selector). Acá un ejemplo

@Marcos Añadido el ejemplo

Intenta con estas modificaciones, espero tus comentarios. Saludos!

No lo probé local ya que local el codigo anterior funcionaba y creo que el problema pude venir por docker. Apliqué los cambios y aún asi el problema persiste, falla por timeout al querer hacer "click". Si sirve, estoy probando el deploy en un servicio gratuito de render. Será cuestión de memoria?
Quedo atento. Gracias marcos!
